# Javascript loop array for form validation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a table form with some rows, that are controlled by user. Meaning they can add as more as they want. Let's pretend user requested 5 rows and i need to check if they all have values.

```
function validateForm() {
   var lastRowInserted = $("#packageAdd tr:last input").attr("name"); // gives me "packageItemName5"
   var lastCharRow = lastRowInserted.substr(lastRowInserted.length - 1); // gives me 5
   var i; 
       for (i = 1; i <= lastCharRow; i++) { 
           var nameValidate[] = document.forms["packageForm"]["packageItemName"].value; 

           if(nameValidate[i].length<1){
              alert('Please fill: '+nameValidate[i]);
               return false;
           }
       }
  }
```

How can i receive packageItemName1 to 5 values in a loop so then I can use to validate them. Want the loop to process this code

```
var nameValidate[] = document.forms["packageForm"]["packageItemName1"].value; 
var nameValidate[] = document.forms["packageForm"]["packageItemName2"].value;
var nameValidate[] = document.forms["packageForm"]["packageItemName3"].value;
var nameValidate[] = document.forms["packageForm"]["packageItemName4"].value;
var nameValidate[] = document.forms["packageForm"]["packageItemName5"].value;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use string interpolation to get the key dynamically:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    const currentValue = document.forms.packageForm[`packageItemName${i}`]
    console.log('current value:', currentValue)
}
```

Comment: Please do not hardcode element lengths and no need to loop either

Comment: the question asked how to loop from packageNameItem1 to packageNameItem5...

Comment: `Let's pretend user requested 5 rows`

Comment: Thanks I really was looking for that  ${i} I would never get that. All works as supposed

Comment: @Simaomp but that is not very efficient nor extendable. If you add a new packageItem, you will need to update the loop

Comment: @mplungjan It is because i only validate when user click to submit. If a new package item row is add by user clicking a keyboard calling this line of code:  $('#packageAdd').append('<tr> <td><input type="text" name="packageItemName'+rowCount+'" value=""></td>\

the validation loop with get the last tr by this line of code, triggered when the submit is clicked(always after the row add) 

var lastRowInserted = $("#packageAdd tr:last input").attr("name");

Comment: @Simaomp [My code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64647218/295783) will validate any number of added packageItemName and does not need the rowCount to know how many. It simply does not care

Comment: @mplungjan perhaps your solution is more generic, but it is also a lot more code. It would be quite trivial to have a variable tracking the rowCount.

Comment: @EthanLipkind "A lot more code? Where is your validation part? And the calling of the validation? My code is 4 lines excluding the unnecessary console.log

Comment: Also your code navigates the DOM 5 times, mine only once

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```js
const validatePackageItems = () => {
  const nameValidate = $("form[name=packageForm] input[name^=packageItemName]"); // all fields with name starting with packageItemName
  const vals = nameValidate.map(function() { return this.value }).get(); // all values
  const filled = vals.filter(val => val.trim() !== ""); // all values not empty

  console.log("Filled", filled, "= ", filled.length, "filled of", vals.length)

  return filled.length === vals.length
};

$("[name=packageForm]").on("submit",(e) => {
  if (!validatePackageItems()) {
    alert("not valid");
    e.preventDefault();
  }    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="packageForm">
  <input type="text" name="packageItemName1" value="one" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="packageItemName2" value="two" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="packageItemName3" value="" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="packageItemName4" value="four" /><br/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```